# How to fix firebase_admob package problem in Flutter

Tags: firebase, gradle, flutter, admob

When I import flutter_admob in my flutter project and run the project it gives an error.

I already tried things android studio offered me(in this tutorial: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility) and I got a different error.
And also I tried connect to firebase and change some version but nothing changed.

Here is the final error message:

Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "D:\android\projects\black_dot\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'D:\android\projects\black_dot\android\app\build.gradle' line: 1
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

  > Could not find method Properties() for arguments [] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUİLD FAILED in 1s
  Command: D:\android\projects\black_dot\android\gradlew.bat app:properties

Finished with error: Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.

Comment: What are the plugin and flutter versions?

Comment: Where can I see versions? Sorry I don't know much about dealing with packages.

Comment: You can see which version of the package you're using from "pubspec.yaml" file. You will see version numbers after the package names